# Piping another parameter into the line in F#

Tags: f#, pipeline

Is piping parameter into line is working only for functions that accept one parameter?
If we look at the example at [Chris Smiths' page](http://blogs.msdn.com/chrsmith/archive/2008/06/14/function-composition.aspx),

```
// Using the Pipe-Forward operator (|>)
let photosInMB_pipeforward =
    @"C:\Users\chrsmith\Pictures\"
    |> filesUnderFolder
    |> Seq.map fileInfo
    |> Seq.map fileSize
    |> Seq.fold (+) 0L 
    |> bytesToMB
```

where his filesUnderFolder function was expecting only rootFolder parameter,
what if the function was expecting two parameters, i.e.
`let filesUnderFolder size rootFolder`

Then this does not work:

```
// Using the Pipe-Forward operator (|>)
let size= 4
let photosInMB_pipeforward =
    @"C:\Users\chrsmith\Pictures\"
    |> filesUnderFolder size
    |> Seq.map fileInfo
    |> Seq.map fileSize
    |> Seq.fold (+) 0L 
    |> bytesToMB
```

Since I can define
`let inline (>>) f g x y = g(f x y)` 
I think I should be able to use pipeline operator with functions having multiple input parameters, right? What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When mixing pipeline operators and curried arguments be aware of the order you pass arguments with.

```
let size = 4
let photosInMB_pipeforward =
    size, @"C:\Users\chrsmith\Pictures\"
    ||> filesUnderFolder
    |> Seq.map fileInfo
    |> Seq.map fileSize
    |> Seq.fold (+) 0L 
    |> bytesToMB
```

Think about it as if the compiler is putting parentheses around the function and its parameters like this.

`@"C:\Users\chrsmith\Pictures\" |> filesUnderFolder size`
becomes
`@"C:\Users\chrsmith\Pictures\" |> (filesUnderFolder size)`
or
`(filesUnderFolder size) @"C:\Users\chrsmith\Pictures\"`

Out of order example

```
let print2 x y = printfn "%A - %A" x y;;

(1, 2) ||> print2;;
1 - 2

1 |> print2 2;;
2 - 1
```

With three arguments

```
let print3 x y z = printfn "%A - %A - %A" x y z;;

(1, 2, 3) |||> print3;;
1 - 2 - 3

(2, 3) ||> print3 1;;
1 - 2 - 3

3 |> print3 1 2;;
1 - 2 - 3
```

Definitions

```
let inline (|>) x f = f x

let inline (||>) (x1,x2) f = f x1 x2

let inline (|||>) (x1,x2,x3) f = f x1 x2 x3
```

Comment: thanks a lot gradbot,
is the value returned from on pipeline, can I treat it as an object? something like: 
size, @"C:\Users\chrsmith\Pictures\"
    ||> filesUnderFolder
    |> .GetLength()

Comment: As an object no but you could create a new function with the `(|>)` operator, also there is no general way to pass a member function as an argument in F#.  You have to wrap it in a function. `size, @"C:\Users\chrsmith\Pictures\" ||> filesUnderFolder |> (fun x -> x.GetLength())`

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks! The way you described thinking about it helped some wheels click in my head for a similar problem.

Answer (score 13):

The example you suggested should work fine, a la

```
let add x y = x + y

41
|> add 1
|> printfn "%d"
```

If `filesUnderFolder` takes two curried args, and you partially apply it to one arg, you can use it in the pipeline for the other.

(Note also the lesser known pipeline operator `||>`

```
(41,1)
||> add
|> printfn "%d"
```

which takes a 2-tuple and feed them sequentially into what follows.)

Comment: |||> is also defined in prim-types.fs :)

Comment: Hey! That pipeline operator is new to me, definitely one to keep up my sleeve.

Comment: Thanks guys. now I can single value or tubles, my next question is can I add a list/array
<code>filesUnderFolder  |> Seq.map FileInfo  
</code>

my problem is I can't process this with pipeline |>, or can I?  
<code>Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetFiles()</code>

Answer (score 4):

It may be bad style (?), but you can add additional parameters to the pipeline 'from the right side'

```
let h x y z = x + y - z

let sub x y = x - y

let sqr x = x * x

3 |> h <| 2 <| 7
  |> sub <| 23
  |> sqr

// is the same as
sqr (sub (h 3 2 7) 23)
```