# Piping a list into the line in F#

Tags: f#, pipeline, forward

Now I can add single [value or tubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330779/piping-another-parameter-into-the-line-in-f) to the pipeline, my next question is can I add a list/array:

```
filesUnderFolder
|> Seq.map FileInfo
```

my problem is I can't process this with pipeline |>, or can I?

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetFiles()
|>Array.map (fun file -> file.ReadAllText().Contains(keyword))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your comment are you trying to do this?

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetFiles() 
|> Seq.map (fun file -> 
    let stream = new StreamReader(file)
    file, stream.ReadToEnd().Contains(keyword))
|> Seq.filter snd
|> Seq.map fst
|> Seq.iter (fun file -> printfn "%s" file.Name)
```

Imperative style can be cleaner.

```
for file in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetFiles() do
    let stream = new StreamReader(file)
    if stream.ReadToEnd().Contains(keyword) then
        printfn "%s" file.Name
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand what is your question about, but correct version is:

```
open System.Reflection
open System.IO

Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetFiles() 
|> Seq.map (fun file -> new StreamReader(file)) 
|> Seq.map (fun file -> file.ReadToEnd().Contains(keyword)) 
|> Seq.iter(printfn "%s")
```

First you need GetExecutingAssembly and you need its result. So `()`.
Second `GetFiles()`, return array of `Stream`, not `FileInfo` as you may expect. Because of this you have to wrap `Stream` to `StreamWriter`.

Thats it.

Comment: Yes, kind of.
However with the code you have written, i can't print the filename/access file value of the second line. Any idea?

Comment: and "your Second" comment is related to the topic of my previous question which was linked...sorry for confusion...

Comment: There is no file names in streams. So you cannot proint it anyway. `ReadToEnd()` reads whole stream. So it will print whole file not line by line. If you need print lines just use ReadLine(). Let me know if you need example.