# Getting rid of function's argument

Tags: c#, f#, ironpython, dsl

It is better to explain my intention with code. So right now I have the following code:

```
class A, IInterfaceUsedByB
{
}

class B
{
    void func(A someObject)
    {
        func2(someObject, 1);
        func3(someObject, "string");
        func4(someObject, new MyObject());

        var anotherObject = someObject.NewInstance;
        func2(anotherObject, 1);
        .......................
    }
    func2(A someObject, int val);
    func3(A someObject, string val);
    func4(A someObject, C val);
}
```

Where `func2`, `func3`, `func4` do need references to someObject. I want to change this to

```
void func(A someObject)
{
    with(someObject,
            () =>
                {
                    func2(1);
                    func3("string");
                    func4(new MyObject());
                }
        );
    var anotherObject = someObject.NewInstance;
    with(anotherObject,
            () =>
                {
                    func2(1);
                    .......................
                }
        );
}
```

Or even better to

```
void func(A someObject)
{
    func2(1);
    func3("string");
    func4(new MyObject());
}
```

So that I don't have to drag this someObject around, but I should still be able to use it inside func2,3,4. In other words it's like setting some context object for a particular code block. I can use any of the three languages (C#, F# or IronPython) for this.

**UPDATE** In the ideal solution class B would be independent of A. `func*` functions only depend on a small interface of A consisting of 2 methods.

**UPDATE2** The someObject can be different for different function calls.

**UPDATE3** I don't think that there's a way to do this only with language primitives like classes, interfaces or extension methods. I think that the solution might be possible with more hackish tools, like attributes, reflection or F#'s computation workflow feature. Or maybe some dynamic features of IronPython. Essentially what I'm trying to do is to create a small embedded DSL.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a global variable?

Comment: In addition to the above two comments/options, perhaps you can use something like Partial Function Application or Currying: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/01/30/currying-vs-partial-function-application.aspx

Comment: @rid `func*` are already methods of another class. Ideally someObject and the class of `func*` should be independent of each other so I can easily replace someObject with another class without changing `func*`s class

Comment: @Cameron Kind of. In this case global variable would work, but I'd rather not use it to make sure the system will work correctly if I decide to make it multithreaded in the future. And there are no global variables in C#. I can emulate them with singletons, but it's not the same.

Comment: "*I can emulate them with singletons, but it's not the same.*" Er, yes, it's exactly the same, which is why everyone loathes singletons as a design pattern.

Comment: @ildjarn It's not the same, because it requires a reference to singleton's class `Singleton.MyObject` instead of just `MyObject`. I'm trying to make a particular part of code as concise as possible. This is the reason I started this function parameter removal in the first place.

Comment: @Max : Different syntax, same semantics -- the same.

Answer (score 1):

Partial function application might work for you here.

```
// object for example first param
var objectInstance = new object();

// partial function application
var func2Partial = new Action<int>((i) => func2(objectInstance, i));
func2Partial(5);
```

If func2 returns something then you'll need to use Func<> rather than Action<>

Alternatively, as per my comment below an extension method may be an option also.

```
internal static class IInterfaceUsedByBExtender
{
    internal static void Func2(this IInterfaceUsedByB obj, int value)
    {
    }

}

// caller
someObject.Func2(5);
```

Another option may be the pipe operator in F#. I have v. basic F# knowledge but I think you can define a function with two params and use the pipe operator to fill the value for the first param. So something like:

```
let printnums x y = printfn "%A - %A" x y;;
```

Can be called by

```
4 |> printnums 5;;
```

Which outputs:

```
4 - 5
```

With func2 you'd have something like

```
let func2 obj, num = ...;
someObject |> func2 1;;
```

More examples of this: [stackoverflow: Piping F# Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330779/piping-another-parameter-into-the-line-in-f)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was trying to do before posting this question. But the code is too complicated. I would be nice if I didn't have to write all those `var func2Partial = new Action<int>((i) => func2(objectInstance, i));`

Comment: how about making func2, func3 and func4 extension methods on the type of someObject? Calling code would then become someObject.func2(5) but you wouldn't need the delegates?

Comment: As I wrote in another comment I'd like `func*` to be independent of the type of someObject.

Comment: Unfortunately, extension methods have to be static and this is not possible in my case.

Comment: @Max added F# piping example

Comment: thanks, but `4 |> printnums 5` is essentially the same as `printnums 5 4`. What I need is `4 |> { printnum 5; printstring "asdfas"; printobject obj }` which is translated to `printnum 5 4; printstring "asdfas" 4; printobject obj 4`

Answer (score 0):

If all those functions operate on one object (sameObject), it looks like you should introduce a class and make them class methods. I don't know what type someObject is of, but here is an example in C#:

```
class Workflow<T>
    where T: class
{
    private readonly T _someObject;

    public Workflow(T someObject)
    {
        _someObject = someObject;
    }


    public void func() 
    {
         func2(1);
         func3("string");
         func4(new MyObject());
    } 

    private void func2(int a) 
    {
        // use _someObject here
    }

    private void func3(string s) 
    {
        // ...
    }
}

// usage
var flow = new Workflow(someObject);
flow.f();
```

Comment: Thanks, but the object is not the same. Moreover I want `func*` to be orthogonal to someObject's type

Answer (score 0):

```
class A, IInterfaceUsedByB
{ 
}

class B<T> where T : A
{
    private T m_SomeObject;

    public B(T someobject)
    {
        m_Someobject = someobject;
    }
    void func()
    {
        func2(1);
        func3("string");
        func4(new MyObject());
    }
    func2(int val) { //Do whatever with m_SomeObject }
    func3(string val) { //Do whatever with m_SomeObject }
    func4(C val){ //Do whatever with m_SomeObject }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that takes a A and returns a func2 function.
For example, if the func2 return type is void (if not, then use Func < int, ReturnType>):

```
        Action<int> func2Gen(A someObject)
        {
           return i => Console.WriteLine(i+someObject.ToString());
        }
```

Then, whereever suited, you can declare

```
var func2=func2Gen(someObject);
```

and call it:

```
func2(1);
```